# One class included to other class by composition. How to change it's private fields?

Tags: java, class

I have simple class:

```
public class Points {

    private int x = 0;

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

And I make other class which have a Points field:

```
public class Curve {

    private Points p;

    public void setX(int x) {
        p.setX(x);
    }
}
```

So, setX(int x) method in class Curve is used to change value of private field x in Points.

Finally I use this method in such way:

```
public class UseComposition {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Curve c = new Curve();
        c.setX(1);
    }

}
```

I think, this code have a doubling: if I change a method name in Points I also have to change method setX in class Curve.
Are there other ways to solve such task? 
May be it isn't a good idea at all to change such private values. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. Just think carefully on the names before continue the work, and you wont have trouble...

Or, you might consider creating an `interface`, that implement basic features that are shared with others. In that way, if you add/change/remove things on the interface, `classes` that have that `interface` implemented will not compile, and show that clearly to you, like:

`Missing Interface method: "setNewX"`...

Answer (score 2):

> I think, this code have a doubling: if I change a method name in Points I also have to change method setX in class Curve.

No you don't. You *can* if you want, but the two methods are independent. You don't *have* to expose all the methods within `Points` at all, and indeed most of the time you wouldn't want to. You should only expose methods which are relevant to the class you're writing. *Sometimes* they may just delegate down via a single field, but often they'll involve multiple fields, or you'll need to do other things as well as calling the delegated method.

Comment: @VladimirS: Not inherently - although you should beware of writing *lots* of pass-through methods. Always consider whether it really makes sense from the point of view of a caller who doesn't know what your class is composed from. The operations need to make sense on the class as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it.  You can provide access to *p* via a public getter like below:

```
public class Curve {

    private Points p;

    public void setX(int x) {
        p.setX(x);
    }

    public Points getPoints(){
        return p;
    }
}
```

After this, you can change the Points class all you want without having to change the method names for both Points and Curve.  You would just have to access *p* like below.

public class UseComposition {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Curve c = new Curve();
    Points p = c.getPoints();
    p.setX(1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use getter in Curve class

```
public Points getPoints() {
    return p;
}
```

then in main method access X property like this:

```
Curve c = new Curve();
Points p = c.getPoints();
p.setX(1);
```

Comment: But Points p is declared as private field. Using this construction, I think, make this field public

Comment: Field remains private. However your setter (method which sets a value of a field) is public.

Comment: I mean Point field appearing on main method because of returned link. But I declare it private in order to avoid a possibility to do p.setX(1) in other classes (and the same to other methods). May be it isn't a good solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use property as `Point` class

```
public class Point {

    private int x = 0;

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}


public class Curve {

    Point cenetrPoint;

    public void setCenterPoint(Point p) {
        this.cenetrPoint = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: But as the result all fields of Points will be changed, but I want to change only one field. I meant this situation.

Comment: I assumed that Point is a class for ONE point, if you assumed other case, it was mistake, T will remove my case. The main approach is Big object contains small objects inside.